# When creating a managed database should I have one instance per application?

Tags: azure, postgresql, database

Let's say I have 10 different applications that all have a postgresql database dependency and these applications must be deployed on Azure using Azure managed postgresql instances.  Would it be best practice to create a managed database instance for each application and each environment (development, staging, production) (10 x 3 = 30 instances) or should I create one larger managed postgresql instance for each environment?  That way I only have three managed database instances (dev, staging, prod)

I'm concerned about performance, security and maintainability.  Overall best practices.

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons for each approach. See discusson on [Should I have one MySQL instance for all our apps, or one instance for each?](https://serverfault.com/questions/182016/should-i-have-one-mysql-instance-for-all-our-apps-or-one-instance-for-each?rq=1)

I've made good experiences with a "mixed" approach:

- development and staging can share the same instance
- production is always on a separate instance (but maybe multiple production apps on the same instance)
- low traffic / low usage / new apps run on a shared instance by default
- once you face a high usage app, and/or start investigating performance issues, create a dedicated instance and move the app there
- same for security issues or db version conflicts (two apps depending on different db version)

Generally, I don't think there's a "best practice" for all scenarios. I would start with a simple setup (i.e. only a few instances), and then improve it when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  This is kind of along the lines of what I was thinking.  I will probably end up going this route.